# Expected Length of Proof in a given Axiomatic System

Tags: logic, foundations, proof-theory, formal-systems

Is there some sort of notion of the expected length of proof taken over the space of all theorems in an axiomatic system or something close to that in the far reaches of pure math? What type of math would study something like that?

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: Do you mean "accepted"?

Comment: No I don't, oops. Expected as in statistical sense of the work. Like excepted value.

Comment: The length of proofs is something that is studied by logicians, but not really in terms of probability in my very limited experience...  See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem